# Combinatorics Split X apples between Y people (with a twist)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Seems that I've lost some of my notes in discrete math. Basically, I will write 3(or 4) examples of types of problems I will encounter. Their solution will do, although I will be grateful if it comes with a few words explaining the thought process.

Problem 1: How many ways can I split up 10 apples between 3 people ?

Problem 2: How many ways can I split up 10 apples between 3 people ? One of them must have atleast 3.

Problem 3: How many ways can I split up 10 apples between 3 people ? One of them must have no more than 4.

Problem 4: How many ways can I split up 10 apples between 3 people ? One of them must have exactly 2, one of them must have no more than 5 and The last one should have at least 3.

These are the questions, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By convention, it is probably assumed here that the apples are identical.

**Problem 1:** For splitting the apples between $3$ people, we have a choice of techniques. A very nice one is often called "Stars and Bars." The Wikipedia article on that is pretty good. You can probably also by searching find a number of explanations of the idea on this site.

However, for $3$ people, there is a more basic way of finding the answer: list all possibilities and count. We will almost do that. Call our $3$ people A, B, and C.

Case 0: Maybe A gets no apples. Then B can get anywhere from $0$ to $10$ apples, with C getting the rest. So there are $11$ ways to distribute the apples with A getting nothing.

Case 1: Maybe A gets $1$ apple. That leaves $9$ to be distributed between B and C. There are $10$ ways to do that (B gets $0$ to $9$ inclusive, and C gets the rest.

Case 2: Maybe A gets $2$ apples. That leaves $8$ to be distributed between B and C. There are $9$ ways to do that.

Continue. The last two cases are Case $9$, where A gets $9$ apples, and there are $2$ ways to distribute the rest, and Case $10$, where A gets everything. There is only one way to do that.

Thus the total number of cases is $11+10+9+8+\cdots +2+1$. We can add by hand. However, probably you are aware of the fact that in general $1+2+3+\cdots +n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. Using that, we get that the number of ways to distribute the apples is $66$.

**Problem 2:** No matter how we split the apples, one person must have at least $3$. For if they all had $\le 3$, that would only account for at most $9$ apples. So saying that one person must have at least $3$ puts no restriction on the splitting, and the answer is the same as for Problem 1.

**Problem 3:** It is clear that no matter how we distribute the apples, one person at least must get $\le 4$. So again the answer is the same as for Problem $1$.

**Problem 4:** As is too often the case, there is some ambiguity in the problem. Does "one of them must get $2$" mean that one particular specific person must get $2$, or that exactly one person must get $2$, or does it mean that at least one person must get $2$? (There was already that kind of ambiguity in Problem 2.)

We interpret the problem as meaning that at least one person gets $2$ apples, at least one of the other people, gets no more than $5$, and one gets at least $3$. If one person (say A) gets $2$, and another (say B), gets no more than $5$, then the remaining person must get at least $3$. So there are not many cases:

Case A: Here A gets exactly $2$. Automatically, one of the others gets no more than $5$, so there are $9$ ways to do the job.

Case B: Here B gets exactly $2$. Again, there are $9$ ways to do this.

Case C: Again $9$ ways.

Add up. We get $27$. But **that's not right** For we have counted the distribution where A gets $2$ and B gets $2$ twice, once in our count of Case A, and once in our count of Case B. Similarly, we have counted A gets $2$ and C gets $2$ twice, also same for B and C. To get the right total, subtract $3$ from $27$. There are other ways to do the count. But one should get $24$.

Comment: Thank you sir, you have helped me a lot!